# Spring Boot backend and Angular frontend application

Tags: angular, spring

I have number of servers and database on each of them. I want to deploy Spring Boot application on each server to get information I need and gather all in presentation layer which would be in Angular.

How should I manage HTTP calls from Angular to Spring Boot ?

Is there any specific approach I should take ? Example would be great.

Comment: Take a look at the JHipster tool. It's a code generator that creates applications with Spring Boot backend and Angular frontend. You can use it to see how the services are exposed in the backend / invoked in the frontend, or you could also build your actual application with the generator.

Answer (score 1):

You would follow the MVC pattern for each Spring Boot application you want to deploy on the servers. I recommend [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=msXL2oDexqw&list=PLqq-6Pq4lTTbx8p2oCgcAQGQyqN8XeA1x) tutorial.

Your Angular application would send HTTP requests for the corresponding SpringBoot application's endpoint (app1/getUsers) for example. Check [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QV7ke4a7Lvc).

You can use the classic Servlet architecture with the synchronous blocking module of thread per request.

Or, you can use Spring's new Reactor stack for asynchronous handling of requests.

Check [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dp_aJh-akkU) for comparison.